# Rewrite regex without positive look-behind

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

I have the following regex that uses look-behind to match different time formats inside a string:

```
(?:(?<=[\s])|^)(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])(?::([0-5]?[0-9]))?( ?[AP]M)?(?:(?=[\s])|$)
```

The regex must match 12-hour or 24-hour time formats, with minutes and optional seconds. Examples:

```
10:00 AM
Time: 10:00 (only the `10:00` part)
13:23:34
```

The regex should entirely reject the following strings:

```
hello10:00 (the time is not separated by whitespace)
24:00:00 (24 does not make sense)
9912:1299 (there's a time substring, but the whole string is not really a time).
```

I'm trying to rewrite it to not use positive look-behind, which is not supported by every web browser. How could I do it?

Comment: What are all the time input formats you want to match?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I would like to match 24-hour and 12-hour formats with minutes and optional seconds.

Comment: On the 2nd line of matches: `Time: 10:00`, is `Time: ` included in match or just the time: `10:00`?

Comment: @zer00ne It should only match `10:00`, not the `Time: `.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you WANT to match and what your do NOT want to match. Do you want the last three to match or not?

Comment: @dawg I have updated the question to clearly show what should be matched and what not, and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const rgx = /\b(?:1?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d(?::[0-5]\d)? ?(?:[ap]m)?\b/gi;
```

| Segment | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `\b` | to the left is a non-word and to the right is a word |
| `(?:1?\d` | begin non-capturing group 0 to 19 |
| `|` | OR |
| `2[0-3])` | 20 to 23 end non-capturing group |
| `:[0-5]\d` | : 00 to 59 |
| `(?::[0-5]\d)? ?` | same as above with a space or nothing |
| `(?:[ap]m)?` | a or p then m or nothing |
| `\b` | to the right is a non-word and to the left is a word |

```js
const rgx = /\b(?:1?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d(?::[0-5]\d)? ?(?:[ap]m)?\b/gi

const str = `
10:00 AM
Time: 10:00
13:23:34
hello10:00
24:00:00
9912:1299`;

const res = [...str.matchAll(rgx)].flat();

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern can be modified to:

```
(?:^|[ \t])(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])(?::([0-5]?[0-9]))?( ?[AP]M)?(?:(?=[\s])|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3kd314/1)

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to not include the leading whitespace in the second match? (`10:00` instead of ` 10:00`).

Comment: `(?:^|[ \t])` is a non-capture group, so just refer to the same capture groups as the regex you have.

Comment: Alternatively, just use the zero width assertion of `\b` instead of `(?:(?<=[\s])|^)` in your regex...